# Does one need to declare java synchronization mechanisms (locks, ,semaphores etc) as volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, semaphore

If a lock/semaphore is being used by multiple threads for synchronization, does one need to declare it as volatile? Are the member variables of locks/semaphores itself guaranteed to reflect the latest state for all threads (similar to volatile variables)?

Comment: We'd need sample code to be sure what you are asking, but taking a guess I'd say locks should be declared final, which is better.  If not final then definitely volatile.  The locks themselves synchronize their internal state, so you don't have to worry about method calls being visible (read about it on the Java doc pages).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you want to make the lock final because once the lock instance is set, you don't want to change it.

But for discussion's sake, if you don't want to make it final, it is in most cases fine if the lock is NOT volatile. What typically happens is that one thread creates some data-structure holding the lock and using safe publication, the object is shared with other threads. Due to this safe-publication, the other threads will see a properly initialized lock.

Safe-publication can be done in various ways like passing the object to the constructor of a thread, using a synchronized block, or using a volatile.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question fundamentally misses the point of how locks, semaphores, etc work.

The specific question asks whether using "volatile" is necessary.
Maybe take a read through the Java Tutorial section [Atomic Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) –
there's some discussion about "volatile" and how to use it, with a primary point being that it's about things *changing*.

Here's a statement to consider using a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) – `Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1)` – along with a few points:

- an object is created: `new Semaphore(1)`
- a reference is declared: `Semaphore s`
- the reference is associated with the object: `s` points to new object

To make use of the "volatile" keyword, you would
designate the reference – `s` – to be volatile (not the object) like this:

```
volatile Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);
```

Why do that? That could be useful if you later allocated a new Semaphore altogether, like: `s = new Semaphore(5)`, and you had concurrency concerns about
all threads seeing the newly allocated `Semaphore(5)` (instead of `Semaphore(1)` which was allocated earlier).

But why do *that*? Why change a shared object at runtime?
The scenarios in which such a thing would happen seem completely unrealistic. The scenario would be: there are threads with a
shared synchronization mechanism (such as a Semaphore), and they're actively running,
actively using the semaphore to coordinate execution...
then somehow, for some reason, the underlying coordination component (the semaphore) changes mid-runtime (?).

I cannot imagine any scenarios where
such a circumstance would arise, other than just flat out doing synchronization incorrectly.

All of this to say: no, do not use "volatile". Instead, use `final`.